# React-Native Audiostreaming

Tags: react-native

does anyone have an idea about a audiostreaming componet which works with the latest react version on both ios and android? I spend the last two days of testing and I also like to share my experiences:

Nice one, outdated does not work:
https://github.com/tlenclos/react-native-audio-streaming

Does not work on the current react-native version:
https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player

Outdated:
https://github.com/andreaskeller/react-native-audioplayer
https://github.com/AllThatSeries/react-native-streaming-audio-player

Runs on android, but not on ios:
https://github.com/indiecastfm/react-native-audio-streamer

Answer (score 0):

After a second try, i used this one again:

https://github.com/indiecastfm/react-native-audio-streamer/

This one works on iOS and Android, but the owner needs to merge this pullrequest:
https://github.com/indiecastfm/react-native-audio-streamer/pull/18